# Location Permission on Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, permissions, request

In my app I need for location of users.

I realize that I must ask for permission, but how I can do this on Android 5.1.1 where user cannot change permission. I wrote the code that is everywhere but without result.

How must I proceed?

```js
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.Manifest;

//import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
//import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
//import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
//import com.google.android.gms.common.api.*;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
        //, OnConnectionFailedListener

{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
   // public GoogleApiClient.Builder mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this);
   private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        //mMainActivity.onConnected(bBundle);

        Log.d("OnCreate", "enter 1");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                //.enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                //       this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                // .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                //.addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .build()
        ;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("OnCreate", "enter in if1 ");

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                Log.d("OnCreate", "enter in if2 ");
                

            } else {
                Log.d("OnCreate", "enter in else2 Request permission ");
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        } else {
            //Request location updates: Popytka
            //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
            Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            Log.d("OnCreate", "enter mLastLocation " + String.valueOf(mLastLocation));
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                Log.d("OnCreate", "enter2");
                latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                Log.d("OnCreate longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
            }
        }
    }
    //public MainActivity mMainActivity = new MainActivity();
    Bundle bBundle;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        //Request location updates:
                        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
                        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                        Log.d("OnCreate", "enter mLastLocation " + String.valueOf(mLastLocation));



                        if (mLastLocation != null) {
                            Log.d("OnCreate","enter20");
                            latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                            longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                            Log.d("OnCreate longitude-0", String.valueOf(longitude));
                        }
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.

                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        //System.out.println("onMapReady in");
        mMap = googleMap;
        //latitude = -34;
        //longitude = 151;
        float zoom = 5;
        double laRe = latitude, loRe = longitude+1;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng user = new LatLng(latitude, longitude), rest = new LatLng(laRe, loRe);
        //LatLng rest = new LatLng(laRe, loRe);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(user).title("Marker in USER"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(user, zoom));


        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(user)
                .radius(200000)
                .strokeColor(0)
                .fillColor(0x4000ff00));

        GroundOverlayOptions restPos = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .position(new LatLng(laRe, loRe), 200000f);
        mMap.addGroundOverlay(restPos);
    }

        @Override
        public void onConnected (Bundle bBundle){

        }

    protected void onStart() {
        //mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
        //mGoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks; //(this);
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        // mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    //@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

}
```

```css
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

SDK 25

Comment: Requesting permissions is requested at Android 6 (M) and above and not on Android 5.1.1..

Comment: Thank you. But when I trying to get location without asking permission I have the same result. Location is null. Meantime when I run GoogleMap on the same device I see my location correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime permission is required for Android 6.0+ but if you need here's the easiest code for requesting runtime permissions.

```
 String [] permissions=new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            };
            List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String permission:permissions) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,permission )!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    listPermissionsNeeded.add(permission);
                }
            }
            if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), 1);
            }
```

> UPDATE

Try this ->

First, create a LocationRequest object:

```
 // Create the LocationRequest object 
 mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
    .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
    .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
```

Then, make sure the user has granted permission to use location. If so, get the location from `requestLocationUpdates` as follows:

```
void getLocation() { 
    Location location = null; 
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);

        /*TODO!! INSERT CODE TO PROMPT USER TO GIVE PERMISSION*/ 

    } else { 
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } 

    mLastLocation = location; 
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,this);
}
```

Be sure to remove the updates if you only need one location without constant monitoring. This way, you will never get a null Location.

Comment: Thank you! Do I understand correctly that on device with Android 5.1.1 requestpermission does not create dialog popup? And has now meaning? But if so, how can I get location? Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient); bring null

Comment: and mark this as answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new in Android (although not in programming itself). Thus too many questions. For example, I change something in build.gradle and now have the error Gradle sync failed: Failed to find Build Tools revision 25.3.1
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) Although it seems I had these tools. I will try as soon I fix this problem. But must I change TargetSDKVersion  from 25 to 22 (I debug on me phone with 5.1.1)?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test since  I cannot go throw  GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                 //.enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                 //       this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                 //.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                 .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                 // .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                 //.addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                 .build(); It worked in my other app but not now. Wow!

Comment: After overcoming previous app stops while executing LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (LocationListener) this); Perhaps again the problem of configuration/libraries

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.coat_of_soul.cycard/com.coat_of_soul.cycard.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.coat_of_soul.cycard.MapsActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener